# How to extract values from html script in server.R

Tags: shiny-server, shiny

I try to build an app that let's users select rectangles on a google Map. The coordinates should than be extracted and used for further calculations. I found an excellent tutorial [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/exchange-data-between-r-and-the-google-maps-api-using-shiny/) on how to interact with the google api and send the data to R. However, I needed to modify the files a bit to have a costum `ui.R` that lets the user select the fields but also select other options important for processing. 
So now I have three files in the same directory.
The html file with the javascript commands for the google api, the ui.R and the server.R.

**index.html**

content can be found in the link above but the important part is:

```
//This function listen to the drawing manager and after you draw the rectangle it extract the coordinates of the NE and SW corners
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'rectanglecomplete', function(rectangle) {  
   var ne = rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast();  
      var sw = rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest();  

      //The following code is used to import the coordinates of the NE and SW corners of the rectangle into R  
      Shiny.onInputChange("NE1", ne.lat());  
      Shiny.onInputChange("NE2", ne.lng());  
      Shiny.onInputChange("SW1", sw.lat());  
      Shiny.onInputChange("SW2", sw.lng());
```

**ui.R**

I use `tags$embed` to embed the `index.html` file in `ui.R`

```
require(shiny)
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Included Content"),
    # mainPanel(
    fluidRow(
      column(9,
             div(style='height:800px; width:1200px; overflow: hidden',
                 tags$embed(src="./index.html", seamless=FALSE,width="100%",height="100%"))),
      column(3,
             h2("Some Calculations"),
             selectInput("Test",label=NA,choices=c("yes","no")),
             selectInput("Test2",label=NA,choices=c("2","3")),
             h3("Coordinates"),
             tableOutput("test"),
             h3("allInput"),
             tableOutput("test2"))

    )
  ))
```

**server.R**

```
# server.R  
library(sp)  
library(rjson)  
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {  
  CorLongLat<<-reactive({
    if(length(input$NE1)>0){ 
      as.data.frame(matrix(c(input$NE2,input$NE1,input$NE2,input$SW1,input$SW2,input$SW1,input$SW2,input$NE1),ncol=2,byrow=T)) 
    }
  })
  output$test<-renderTable({
    CorLongLat()
  }) 

  output$test2<-renderTable({
    as.data.frame(reactiveValuesToList(input))%>%gather(ID,Value)
  }) 

})
```

However, if I try to disply all inputs via `output$test2<-renderTable({
    as.data.frame(reactiveValuesToList(input))%>%gather(ID,Value)
  })`

it showes only the controls that are directly embeded in the `ui.R`. How do I access the variables `NE1,NE2,SW1,SW2` from `index.html` that are created via  `Shiny.onInputChange`?

**EDIT**
In the meantime I got a little closer to the core of the problem. Running the App with `options(shiny.trace=TRUE)` tells me after launching the app the following

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4840
SEND {"config":{"workerId":"","sessionId":"16000363ddc17409cd5fdf25c038b61d"}}
RECV {"method":"init","data":{"Test":"yes","Test2":"2",".clientdata_output_test4_hidden":false,".clientdata_pixelratio":1,".clientdata_url_protocol":"http:",".clientdata_url_hostname":"127.0.0.1",".clientdata_url_port":"4840",".clientdata_url_pathname":"/",".clientdata_url_search":"",".clientdata_url_hash_initial":"",".clientdata_singletons":"",".clientdata_allowDataUriScheme":true}}
SEND {"errors":[],"values":[],"inputMessages":[]}
SEND {"config":{"workerId":"","sessionId":"0881062c26c882de2d0648a96ed98296"}}
RECV {"method":"init","data":{".clientdata_output_json_hidden":false,".clientdata_pixelratio":1,".clientdata_url_protocol":"http:",".clientdata_url_hostname":"127.0.0.1",".clientdata_url_port":"4840",".clientdata_url_pathname":"/index.html",".clientdata_url_search":"",".clientdata_url_hash_initial":"",".clientdata_singletons":"",".clientdata_allowDataUriScheme":true}}
SEND {"errors":[],"values":[],"inputMessages":[]}
```

After selecting a triangle on the map I get

```
RECV {"method":"update","data":{"NE1":67.40748724648756,"NE2":-11.77734375,"SW1":62.552856958572896,"SW2":-26.9384765625}}
```

And after selecting on `selectInput` :

```
RECV {"method":"update","data":{"Test2":"3"}}
```

I think the problem here is the second sessionID that is established. How do I refer to those in `server.R` or how do I combine both into on?

Comment: Check this out https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/sending-data-from-client-to-server-and-back-using-shiny/

Comment: Thanks, I think I got closer to the problem (See my edits)